# Is there a bootable ISO out there that does a performance check on PCs?

Tags: boot, performance, iso-image, compact-disc

I am looking for something that checks CPU speed, memory, disk, graphics, in the same way done by the Windows performance index. I need a bootable ISO.

Comment: phoronix test suite comes close, but there's no preinstalled iso with it. I do believe with sufficient ram, you can install it on top a plain vanilla *buntu disk, however

Answer (score 5):

Try [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) it has some useful tools among which there are some speed testing tools (according to their website) but I am not sure how good they are. Usually I use this tool to test hardware for problems.

There's also special USB Bootable PenDrive to be bought from [Passmark](http://www.passmark.com/products/bootable-usb-flash-drive.htm) or [special test kit](http://www.passmark.com/products/pc-test-kit.htm) that bundles it all if you can spend some money.

All in all I'm pretty sure you can get most of the benchmarking software working from boot CD if you prepare one yourself using WinPE. Most should work just fine if you know what you're doing. Actually I'm pretty sure the USB PenDrive from Passmark is WinPE on USB Stick with their tools so if you're skilled enough you can make one yourself using their software without having to pay additional money for the hardware (Depends on price comparison as I didn't check if it's worth the time to invest to build one yourself).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article about benchmarking with Ubuntu

[Benchmark PC Hardware To Diagnose System Issues With Ubuntu Live Disk [Guide]](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/benchmark-pc-hardware-to-diagnose-system-issues-with-ubuntu-live-disk/?utm_source=AddictiveTips%20List&utm_campaign=93453b8f96-RSS_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN&utm_medium=email)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Performance test](http://www.passmark.com/),it's a great utility.

Other [benchmarks](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-free-benchmark-programs/)

1. [3DMark 06 / PCMark 05](http://www.futuremark.com/)
2. [Novabench](http://novabench.com/)
3. [SiSoft Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/)
4. [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)

Comment: These are all installed software solutions, not bootable off CDs.

Comment: @Keltari tags are great but critical info needs to be in the title and question also.